# Fork Join Pool vs Fixed Thread Pool for akka http client-focused workload?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, forkjoinpool

I have a fork join dispatcher configured for a service that only uses the client side of akka http (via a host connection pool):

```
my-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "fork-join-executor"

  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 256
    parallelism-factor = 128.0
    parallelism-max = 2048
  }

}
```

The only thing the service logic does is request from an external source, unmarshal it using jawn, and then transform the jawn ast into a case class:

```
def get(uri: Uri)[T]: Future[T] = {
    for {
      response <- request(uri)
      json <- Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Try[JValue]]
    } yield json.transformTo[T]
  }
```

I was wondering if it would be more efficient to use a fixed thread pool for this kind of workload. This service gets around 150 req/s and I'd like to keep CPU usage under 1 CPU (it currently hovers at around 1.25-1.5 CPUs).

Comment: Your choices for fork-join-executor parameters seem excessive by any measure. Check the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html#Setting_the_dispatcher_for_an_Actor) for more guidelines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [wisdom of the ancients](http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/01/choosing-executorservice.html), your workflow is I/O bound so you should pick an execution context backed by a `CachedThreadPool`, however if throttling is desired you should back your context with a `FixedThreadPool`.

Also, depending on the deployment environment you may be able to limit the Java process to one core at the OS level by [setting CPU affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882885/is-it-possible-to-force-an-existing-java-application-to-use-no-more-than-x-cores).